# Can an expanded version of an article be considered an unpublished work?

Tags: publishing

I submitted an entry to a contest that requires the work not be published. I met that criterion. I have substantially rewritten the article - it's now six pages instead of two. Basically expanded a short work to a full chapter for a book. The contest announcements are in October. My question is, are the two works considered different or are the same since they're on the same basic topic?

Comment: Your question is _will publishing the enlarged version breach your agreement with the contest organisers_. That is a matter of law (not writing) and will depend upon what you signed and the jurisdiction within which the contest is based.

Comment: @Fortiter - Agreed. This depends on the terms of the contest as much as anything else. Without knowing more about that, this question is difficult to answer.

Comment: Welcome to Writers! Please don't take our criticisms as hostility; we welcome questions like these, and only look to improve them. I hope you find this site useful.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the contest. If it is clearly mentioned as a part of their rules and regulations that the article should not be an extended / revised version of a published one, I would give it a skip. If it doesn't, as a matter of ethics, I would inform / confirm from the authority if it is acceptable.

I would suggest confirming with the committee now itself, as in case of a no, you still have some time left to work on a new article.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is the content that matters. No matter how long or short the article is .

The article should not be less than the minimum number of words required. If they are more, its fine.

Further, regarding the length as per my opinion ; the policy is not breached.

Still you can check this with rules and regulations of the contest.